# Email Reply Notifications in Office 365 API

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm hooking a custom CRM app into office 365 emails using the graph sdk and web hooks (or notifications as the doc calls it) to listen to the inbox so that when a user sends or receives a message from outlook (or any client) the CRM system saves the email in a database and grabs attachments.

So far I've successfully wired everything up for when a user receives an email using the `created` notification, but I can't figure out how to interpret and capture the data from when a user hits reply and sends or when they create a new message and send - When I subscribe to the `edit` notification (and I'm just assuming the `delete` notification isn't helpful here) it just sends me a copy of the original message when the user replies and doesn't send me anything when they create and send a new email.

Any doc references or tutorials on this will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I'd guess the original message now has the "You replied to this message" property set (which in MAPI looks like it's [PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7eac8965-674a-427b-a24f-9de2fbaa8d61/how-to-remove-you-replied-to-this-message-on?forum=outlookdev) - apologies I don't know if that translates into the graph API too) and I'd guess you can then find the reply by Conversation Index. But I'm guessing based on MAPI, and there may be a more convenient way.

Comment: You can try to use Microsoft's [MFCMAPI](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mfcmapi) tool in order to inspect all available message properties.